# Tomcat compiles JSPs at Java 7 level. Can I change this setting within the WAR file rather than in Tomcat configuration?

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration

I have a Java web application, packaged as a WAR file, deployed to a Tomcat 8.5.49 servlet container.  The JSPs in my application use some Java 8 syntax.  By default, Tomcat 8.5.49 compiles JSPs at the Java 7 level.  This can be overridden in the Tomcat configuration file `$CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml` ([as documented here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jasper-howto.html)).

Out of the box, Tomcat has this section in its `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

And you change the Java version by adding two new `init-param`s, `compilerSourceVM` and `compilerTargetVM`:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
        <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>fork</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>xpoweredBy</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>3</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

I would like to find a way to do the same thing but without touching the Tomcat configuration file.  I'm building a Docker image based on an official Tomcat image and would like to change it as little as possible, to make future upgrades less complicated.

**Is there a way to override the default language version level for JSP compiling from within my web app?** For example, can I do something in the `web.xml` file in the `WEB-INF` subdirectory of my WAR file?